# how to send mail with data that data from database using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

this is my code: i am getting perfect output in postman.but i want the output to send through my mail.In this code var result i am getting error i cannot able to get the responses.

var startBroadcasting = function (req, res) {

```
authToken = req.headers.authorization;
userAuthObj = JSON.parse(UserAuthServices.userAuthTokenValidator(authToken));
var todayDate = new Date();
var expireDate = new Date(userAuthObj.expire_date);
tokenOK = TokenValidator.validateToken(userAuthObj.user_id, authToken).then(function (userSessions) {
    if (userSessions.length === 1) {
        if (expireDate >= todayDate) {
            template_id = req.params.id;
             image_id = req.params.img_id;
            TemplateController.findById(template_id, {
                attributes: {
                    exclude: ['created_by', 'created_on', 'updated_by', 'updated_on']
                },
                include: [{
                    attributes: {
                        exclude: ['created_by', 'created_on', 'updated_by', 'updated_on']
                    },
                    model: Broadcasting,

                    where: {
                        id: image_id,

                    }
                },

            ]
            }

            ).then(function (templatefindByid) {



                BccSetting.findAll({
                    where: {
                        template_id: template_id
                    }
                }).then(bccSettings => {


                    res.status(200).json({
                        id: templatefindByid.id,
                        name: templatefindByid.name,
                     template_images: templatefindByid.template_images,
                        bcc_settings: bccSettings,


})
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(404).json({
                        message: ' not  found...'
                    });
                });
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'not  found...'
                });
            });
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Not ...'
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Expired...'
        });
    }
}).catch(function (err) {
    res.status(401).json({
        message: 'Expired...'

    });
});
```

var result = "

#### Hi " + template_images.client_name + "!

We are pleased to inform you that  " + template_images.client_name + " newschannel streaming has been stopped sucessfully on " +template_images.destination_type + "

" +
  "" +
 "This email was sent from a notification-only address that cannot accept incoming email. Please do not reply to this message.";

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

```
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
auth: true,
active: true,
secure: true,
requireTLS: true,
 auth: {
     user: 'trans@gmail.com',
    pass: 'wertyy'
}
```

});

let mailOptions = {

```
from: 'trans@gmail.com',
 to: 'wwww@gmail.com',
 bcc: bcc_setting.bcc_setting,// here i want bcc setting data
subject: 'yvnuyybymyed',
html: 'result'
```

};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {

```
if (error) {
    return console.log("mail not sent" + error.message);
}
console.log('success');
```

});

};

Comment: I think `mailOptions.html: 'result'` should be `mailOptions.html: result`.

Comment: res.status(200).json({
                        id: templatefindByid.id,
                        name: templatefindByid.name,
                     template_images: templatefindByid.template_images,
                        bcc_settings: bccSettings,
})

Comment: in the above response i want to send mail.for example i want the template images data means how to declare that response

Comment: It's absolutly not clear what you want to do. Please edit and format your question.